# Diagram Problem

Tags: tikz-cd, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

I need a diagram, I have attached the shape below, this is my attempt but it didn't work as I wanted, I would be very grateful if you can help me.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d,Rightarrow,"\not\Uparrow"]\arrow[r,Rightarrow, "\not\Leftarrow"] & B \arrow[d,Rightarrow,"\not\Uparrow"]\\
C \arrow[r,Rightarrow,"/" marking,"\not\Leftarrow"] &D 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Don't sweat it when people give you the gears for your questions; it happens to all the new people - I remember when I was new :-). This is a pretty basic diagram, and I'd personally use either TikZ or tikz-cd. (probably tikz-cd). Have fun!

Comment: Please add what you tried and maybe tell a bit more concretely what you want to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice welcome

Answer (score 7):

You can use `shift left=` or `shift right=` to get two arrows side by side. The direction of the shift is from the perspective of the arrow, so in the example all arrows are shifted to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\slsh}{\diagup}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt]\arrow[r, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt] 
    & B \arrow[d, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt]\arrow[l, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt, "\slsh"marking]\\
C \arrow[r, Rightarrow,"\slsh"marking, shift right=3pt]\arrow[u, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt, "\slsh"marking] 
    &D \arrow[u, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt, "\slsh" marking]\arrow[l, Rightarrow, shift right=3pt, "\slsh"marking]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

If you want a smaller slash, changing the font size won't work because the slash won't be vertically centered with respect to the arrow. But you can use the `decorations.markings` library to create a `not` style that can be added to any arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{not/.style={
    decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\node[scale=.7][transform shape]{/};}}, postaction={decorate}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt]\arrow[r, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt] 
    & B \arrow[d, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt]\arrow[l, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt, not]\\
C \arrow[r, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt, not]\arrow[u, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt, not]
    &D\arrow[u, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt, not]\arrow[l, Rightarrow, shift right=2.5pt, not]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```