Stroked arrow in xymatrix
I'd like to know whether there exists are more "official" way of stroking an xymatrix arrow than the following:
\ar[r]|{\setminus}


Somethink like this?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=2pc{ A\ar[r]|{\setminus}& B \\
C \ar[r]|{\backslash} & D \\
E \ar[r]|{\object@{/}} & F \\
G \ar[r]|{\diagup}& H
}
\end{document}



In fact, in the end I used a variety of symbols, because my arrows point in all sorts of directions, whereas the symbol stays oriented the same way.

@AlgebraicsAnonymous If you put the minimal working example (i.e. your code tex) we can solve your problem.

Yes, sorry, I just assumed that the solution that would come up would be rotation invariant. I'll post something in short order.

@AlgebraicsAnonymous See my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708486/diagram-problem/717289#717289
